# How to apply the search in list type field in dynamodb?

Tags: java, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb

We are using $all in mongodb repository like below:

```
@Query(value = "{ 'subscriptions' : {$all : ?0 }}")

public List<ContentItem> findBySubscription(String[] subscriptionCode);
```

it works good for mongo but we need its alternative in dynamodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below solution uses **AWS SDK DynamoDB**. Currently, I think there is only community version of Spring data available for DynamoDB. So, I have provided the solution using **AWS SDK**.

[QuerySpec Class](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/spec/QuerySpec.html)

The **`CONTAINS`** comparison operator can be used to search for the values in LIST data type.

> CONTAINS is supported for lists: When evaluating "a CONTAINS b", "a"
>   can be a list; however, "b" cannot be a set, a map, or a list.

**Example:-**

```
QuerySpec querySpec = new QuerySpec();
querySpec.withKeyConditionExpression("yearkey = :yearval and title = :title")
                .withFilterExpression("contains (subscriptions, :subscriptions)")
                .withValueMap(
                        new ValueMap().withNumber(":yearval", yearKey)
                        .withString(":title", title) 
                        .withString(":subscriptions", subscriptions));
```

**Edit:-**

Currently, the second parameter can't be list because the API can't process it as per the specification. The workaround would be to use **AND** condition with **multiple CONTAINS**. Example below:-

```
.withFilterExpression("contains (subscriptions, :subscriptions1) AND contains (subscriptions, :subscriptions2)")
```

Comment: In my case b will be also a list. I need to find alternative of $all of MongoDb. Please suggest.

Comment: Thanks @notionquest

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if it is helpful?